# ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - <Communications link failure Docker + Spring + Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and when I run my docker-compose file I got this error: ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - <Communications link failure. Somehow my app cannot connect to the database.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_vol:/var/lib/mysql
       - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password1234
       MYSQL_DATABASE: app1
       MYSQL_USER: user1234
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: user1234
     ports:
       - 3306:3306
   phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password1234
   web:
    build:
      context: .       
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: tomcat
    volumes:
      - ./target/ffengine-webb.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ffengine-webb.war
      - ./logs/:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/
    ports:
      - '8082:8080'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app1
      MYSQL_USER: user1234
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user1234
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/app1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
volumes:
    db_vol:
```